# Trying to get Linux KDE working with steam(Chromebook OS & crouton)

Tags: software-center, kde, steam, chromebook

Just a heads up, have never used Linux before so don't be too harsh

I've installed KDE Linux on my chromebook using crouton for around a month and it's been awful. I'm not entirely sure how to use it and have installed and reinstalled it several times to make sure that it's not something that occurs during the download. To name a few issues I'm not sure how to control the window size and it doesn't seem like it can be manipulated anywhere, sometimes I can't type in the url for the browser or for software center's search bar and have to reset the system to get it working, and items like firefox are corrupt upon installation and steam can't be installed at all. I don't have the "authority" to install firefox through software center and have to do it through the konsole which corrupts it and steam is displayed as "not found" after selecting it through software center.

Comment: "KDE Linux" is not a Linux distro. KDE is a desktop environment. Which of [these](https://community.kde.org/Distributions) did you install?

Answer (score 0):

As the wise elder mentioned, KDE is the desktop enviroment(DE), just like Unity, Gnome, Xfce4, Lxde, and more, are all DE's.

In short, you'll need to run the software store from inside the term using, "gksu," as opposed to "sudo." That will give you the permissions you seek. It's nothing you likely need to worry about, but be aware that there are disasterously vague consequences to running gksu that one should be made aware of. But, none of it concerns you...

Can you tell me what distro release you chose? Like, was it 14.04(Trusty), 16.04(Xenial), or something else? The two I named are stable releases, but you may have installed a non-stable release. Either way, KDE will work. That said,
what Chromebook are you using, what are the specs?
KDE is pretty, and mostly a very intuitive DE, with an almost Mac Os feel to it at times. Worth looking into, I'm actually putting the finishing touches on my KDE setup as I type this.

But, the pretty interface has a price, and many Chromebooks do not have the internals to efficiently run this DE. I'd say you're looking at the higher end of the Mid-range to the more premium Chromebooks.
I'm currently running Kubuntu KDE Framework, PLasma 5.11 on my Hp Chromebook 13 G1 w/intel core m7 and 16GB of ram.
These specs are absolutely not required,so I suppose I'm mostly just vamping.